# How to connect and get attributes for ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto

How do I connect to a specific instance (i-123456) using boto and perform some operation on that?
I know we can get all reservations and get the instances from that.. but would like to know if there is a way to do it particular for that instance?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what particular you need do for that instance?  somthing like this `conn.stop_instances(instance_ids=['instance-id-1'])` ? or something else?

Answer (score 1):

To connect to Amazon EC2 instances, you need to use SSH (or RDP if your instance is running Windows) and authenticate yourself using an SSH private key (details are available at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html)

Boto is a Python Library to make AWS API calls. Some calls let you get details about instances and perform actions on them, such as stopping, starting, terminating, attaching EBS volumes etc ...

Boto does not allow to connect to instances.

Details about the Python Boto SDK and some code sample for common operations are available at http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ec2_tut.html

Comment: thank you, but my question was misleading.
connect in my sense was boto ec2 connection.
so I would want to know if there is a do ec2connecto_istnace('i-212344') and some operation on it using the boto methods which we have. not via ssh

Comment: There is a component in boto called cmdshell (http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/manage.html#module-boto.manage.cmdshell) that allows you to execute commands on an EC2 instance but it is still using SSH.  It just does it programmatically.